# Matern covariance increasing with smoothness

Tags: covariance, spatial, identifiability, spatial-correlation

Consider the Matern covariance function with the following parametrization:

$$C_{\nu,\phi,\sigma}(h) = \sigma^2 \frac{2^{1-\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)}\left(\sqrt{2\nu}\frac{h}{\phi} \right)^\nu K_\nu (\sqrt{2\nu} \frac{h}{\phi})$$

where $K_\nu$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind, and $\nu, \phi, \sigma^2$ are positive parameters referred to as the smoothness, scale, and nugget parameters, respectively. I am investigating the identifiability of this function's parameters under various conditions and am a little stuck on the following question:

For fixed $h$ and scale parameter $\phi$ (and nugget $\sigma^2$), is it true that the Matern covariance function is monotone increasing in $\nu$?

It is clear that for all other parameters fixed, it is monotone in $\phi$ but this seems a little less obvious for the smoothness parameter $\nu$ for the Matern covariance function.